# Extract values from a multidimensional array using php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this which has been posted to a php script

```
Array
(
     [users] => Array
           (
              [0] => Array
                    (
                         [onlineid] => person1
                         [comment] => comment1
                         [img] => image1
                    )

              [1] => Array
                    (
                         [onlineid] => person2
                         [comment] => comment2
                         [img] => image2
                    )
           )
)
```

In php, i firstly need to obtain only the onlineid from each array item so that it can be used in a select statement (mysql) to see if the user exists.

Then secondly or at the same time i need to loop through each onlineid in the array and extract the values for each key (like the comment and image in the example) so that they can be used to update a mysql database.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: You already said you need to loop. What else do you need to know? What is your problem? You also should go back to your previous questions and accept the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: Hi Felix. Thanks. Im not sure how to actually obtain the values from the array. Ive never used the syntax. I didnt accept a previous answer yet as im not sure which one is going to be the right one. It depends on this.

Comment: If you are not familiar with arrays, I suggest you have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php. Arrays are the most important data structure in PHP. And as far as I can tell, every answer to your previous question will let you leave with an array.

Comment: Thank you once again felix. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$myAry = array(...); // the one you have listed in your question

// goes through each user entry in the array, and makes it an individual
// variable we can reference (in this case '$user')
foreach ($myAry['users'] as $user)
{
  // create the update query using the values from the element
  $sql = "UPDATE mytable
          SET    comment={$user[comment]},
                 img={$user[img]}
          WHERE  onlineid={$user[onlineid]}";
  // pass it off to mysql (or whatever connection you want)
  if (($result = mysql_query($sql)) !== false)
  {
    // all went well, ...additional code here...
  }
}
```

Or am I missing the point on this one?

Comment: Thats great. What would happen if the user doesn't exist in the table? Would there be an error when trying to update? In my mind i thought it best to check the the user exists first. But im no expert. I guess you could do a select statement the same way and then an if condition.

Comment: @Aparistar: You can perform an update/create in one query, just depends on your SQL version. What is the database you're working with, MySQL? (e.g. the [REPLACE INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) command for MySQL)